# Using add_compile_definitions() for a value that initializes an array

Tags: c++, c, cmake, c-preprocessor

I am attempting to initialize a `uint8_t` array with a preprocessor definition that is overwritten in a CMakeLists.txt file. For example:

```
#ifndef MY_CHAR_ARRAY
#define MY_CHAR_ARRAY {0x00, 0x01, 0x02}
#endif
```

`uint8_t str[3] = MY_CHAR_ARRAY;`

What is the syntax, if it exists, to overwrite `MY_CHAR_ARRAY` using `add_compile_definitions()` in my CMakeLists.txt file?

I have made various guesses of the syntax:

`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC})`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA}{0xBB}{0xCC}`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA},{0xBB},{0xCC}`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA} {0xBB} {0xCC}`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA0xBB0xCC}`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA 0xBB 0xCC}`
`add_compile_definitions(MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAABBCC}`

with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: What exact `add_compile_definitions()` calls have you tried? Don't make us guess with `<INSERT CHAR ARRAY HERE>` and `{0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC}` or `{0xAA}{0xBB}{0xCC}`. Show it exactly.

Comment: See disclaimer at the end of https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS. Put the macro definition in a `config.h` header instead.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/v6f8jYPzv) if you insist the array to source within CMake, but in the end you still need the config.h as comments above

Comment: @haleyk and user17732522
Thank you for your replies. The reason I am trying to do this is to avoid directly modifying a git submodule, which requests that you replace a hard-coded #define in a header file. Thus, the config.h header file would not work for that specific use-case. I may just need to fork the submodule's repository, or there is another entirely different solution that I'm overlooking.

Comment: No don't use macros in C++ unless you really don't have any other choice (string concatenation) make a header file and add `inline constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t,3> MY_CHAR_ARRAY{0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC}` and use that

Comment: `The reason I am trying to do this is to avoid directly modifying a git submodule` What git "submodule" exactly? What project exactly? `which requests that you replace a hard-coded #define in a header file` Typically `configure_file` is used to generated `config.h`. `the config.h header file would not work for that specific use-case` Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the whole string in double quotes.

```
add_compile_definitions("MY_CHAR_ARRAY={0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC}")
```

Prefer `target_compile_definitions`.